# Forbidden: You don't have permission to access /abcd/ on this server

Tags: php, apache, server, permissions, cakephp-2.0

I am running a **CentOS 6.9 OS**. I have **Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)** Server running. I have a *cakephp 2* application that I want to run here. I have an `index.php` file inside `/var/www/html` that runs perfectly. I have another folder called test inside `/var/www/html`.

Inside that folder there is an `index.php` file. Test folder also runs perfectly. But whenever I try to run the cakephp application from the browser I get the message I don't have permission to access that folder. The cakephp application has `0777` permission. Inside my `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` file there is written -

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

So I don't know what I am doing wrong and what more I can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi dude please find and edit httpd.conf file, which is in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf. and paste the code below

```
<Directory "/">
#Options FollowSymLinks
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
AllowOverride None
Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory "/home/">
 #Options FollowSymLinks
 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
 AllowOverride None
 Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Then kindly restart the server if the problem still appear

disable the seLinux in `/etc/selinux/config` change `SELINUX=disabled` and restart the server it again hope it works now ^_^

Comment: did you restart the server ?

Comment: yes, I did restart the server. It is still not working

Comment: <Directory "/">and <Directory "/home/"> header did you change it to your home path folder ?

Comment: restorecon -r /var/www/html did it for me

Answer (score 0):

`restorecon -r /var/www/html` does the job

I got the answer from here. https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=6834